# how big can a Heroku Postgres database be?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have a Heroku database ($200 plan). THe database is quite simple: it contains user clicks. There are about 10 fields in the main table, some fields are indexed, and the table contains about several hundred million rows currently.

The main select query is - searching by indexed field (click ID). It is quite fast, as an indexed query should be.

My main concern is database growth. The database is currently 250GB in size, and it keeps increasing. Every month it grows by 25 GB.

Will there be a limit when the DB slows down and I will have to do something about it (partitioning etc)? What will this limit look like? 1TB? 10TB? 100 TB?

[image]

Comment: That depends on your query and its execution plan. You might want to partition so that you can get rid of old data.

Comment: yes but what if I dont? When will it create problems?

Comment: Perhaps. That depends on your queries and their execution plans.